# Synchronizing without an object reference

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

My online course gave me a project, where I have to write to the individual files with their corresponding threads. They also gave me a guideline, which is shown here:

```
public static void writeToFile(String saveState, String fileName) { 
    //TODO: Write a string to a new file synchronously
}

public static void writeToFileAsync (String saveState, String fileName) {
    //TODO: Write a string to a new file asynchronously
    
    new Thread() {
        public void run(){    
            writeToFile(saveState fileName);
        }
    }.start();
}
```

I have to make these methods work when I call them by these following statements:

```
FileManager.writeToFileAsync(ticTacToe.toString(),"ttt.txt");
FileManager.writeToFileAsync(connectFour.toString(),"c4.txt");
FileManager.writeToFileAsync(mastermind.toString(),"mm.txt");
```

According to this guideline, since both methods aren't synchronized, I used a synchronized block instead.

```
public class FileManager {
    public static void writeToFile(String saveState, String fileName) {
        synchronized(FileManager.class) {                                  //Locks the class..?
            try(FileWriter fout = new FileWriter(fileName)){
                fout.write(saveState);
            } catch (IOException exc) {
                System.out.println("Error occurred while writing to a file.");
            }
        }
    }
    
    public static void writeToFileAsync(String saveState, String fileName) {
        new Thread() {
            public void run(){
                System.out.println("Writing to a file: " + fileName);

                synchronized(FileManager.class) {      //Also locks the class?      
                    writeToFile(saveState, fileName);
                    System.out.println("Done writing to a file: " + fileName);
                }

            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

I haven't learned about synchronization based on locking a class nor this concept of "new Thread()" statement. (I guess they make a new thread..?) Of course, this code is NOT SYNCHRONIZED AT ALL. Here's one of the outcomes:

```
Writing to a file: c4.txt
Writing to a file: mm.txt
Writing to a file: ttt.txt
Done writing to a file: c4.txt
Done writing to a file: ttt.txt
Done writing to a file: mm.txt
```

My desired outcome:

```
Writing to a file: ttt.txt
Done writing to a file: ttt.txt
Writing to a file: c4.txt
Done writing to a file: c4.txt
Writing to a file: mm.txt
Done writing to a file: mm.txt
```

So can anybody please tell me about this concept of ***locking a class*** and ***new Thread()***?

Comment: If you are writing to different files there's no synchronization required, the OS handles it all.  It's not clear to me though if that's what you are asking.

Comment: Shouldn’t it be the task of your online course to explain these things? It makes no sense at all to give you an assignment about things you haven’t learned yet. Besides that, letting the missing comma aside, the `writeToFileAsync` is already complete. You only have to remove the `// TODO` comment and implement the synchronous `writeToFile` method. The “guideline”, if you want to call two code comments as such, do nowhere say that you should insert `synchronized` blocks. Besides that, since the first print statement is *outside* the `synchronized` block, the result should not surprise you.

Comment: 1. Your code is correctly synchronized. And you can remove the synchronized block from writeToFileAsync, since writeToFile already uses the same lock on the class (on the Class instance's monitor). 2. To achieve the required output, you have to move your System.out.println-s from writeToFileAsync to writeToFile, because you start and finish the writing in writeToFile, not in writeToFileAsync.

Comment: @markspace I know that they're not going to cause any error or make a different outcome, but... the method is required to be synchronized.

Comment: @Holger Well, apparently I double-checked the course materials but couldn't find anything about "new Thread( )" and class synchronization. And yes, that missing comma... well, they seem to be human too... So, ***thank you*** for helping me! It wasn't the synchronization that was messing up the code. (That one println...)

Comment: @AnatolyG Thank you for letting me know! I now realized my mistake about the println... (I make dumb mistakes a little too often) Again, thanks to everybody in this comment for helping me! (...and sorry for the late reply)